# What exactly in the sudo behavior is unpredictable?

Tags: sudo, tty, docker, signals

In the [Best practices for writing Dockerfiles guide](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/) of the docker documentation, we can read:

> Avoid installing or using sudo since it has unpredictable TTY and signal-forwarding behavior that can cause problems. If you absolutely need functionality similar to sudo, such as initializing the daemon as root but running it as non-root), consider using “gosu”.

My questions are:

- What exactly in the `sudo` behavior is unpredictable?
- Which problems can it cause?
- Is it a feature or a bug of `sudo`?

Comment: Maybe this is one of reason https://ruderich.org/simon/notes/su-sudo-from-root-tty-hijacking